# Symfony2 Images routes in tinymce with elfinder

Tags: symfony, tinymce, elfinder

I`am using Simfony2 with StfalconTinymceBundle and FMElfinderBundle.
I have problem when puting images fron elfinder to tinymce. I want image route to be '/uploads/elfinder/image.jpg' but I get something like '../../../../elfinder/image.jpg'

My config.yml for elfinder is

```
fm_elfinder:
instances:
    default:
        locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
        editor: tinymce4 # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, form, custom and simple
        fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
        theme: smoothness # jquery theme
        include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
        connector:
            debug: false # defaults to false
            roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                uploads:
                    show_hidden: false # defaults to false
                    driver: LocalFileSystem
                    path: uploads/elfinder
                    upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                    upload_deny: ['all']
                    upload_max_size: 2M
```

Tinymce configuration is

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
include_jquery: true
tinymce_jquery: true
selector: ".tinymce"
theme:
    advanced:
        theme: "advanced"
        file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser
        plugins:
            - "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
            - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
            - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
            - "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code"
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | stfalcon | example"
        image_advtab: true
```

Thanks

Comment: HI @nlan, can you post Tinymce configuration too?

Comment: Hi @helios. Please look at Tinymce configuration.

Comment: Configuration looks alsmost fine (mine is https://gist.github.com/helios-ag/2abd77f3d6e02d0ea8ab), do you develop under windows platform? Also tinymce has some configuration related to relative paths for images (look at http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php)

Comment: Thanks for your response @helios . Now I have image path something like '../../../../uploads/elfinder/image.jpg'. I`am develop under ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Hi @nlan, does your project under vhost (like symfony.dev/app_dev.php) or under localhost/web/symfony/..../app_dev.php?

Comment: After reading the doc I got it. I add to tinymce config `relative_urls: true. Thank you!